# Setting a file's icon in java

Tags: java

```
//Getting a file's icon
File file = new File("t2.png");
FileSystemView view = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();       
Icon icon = view.getSystemIcon(file);
```

Getting a file's icon can be done as above code in java.

What about setting a file's icon? How can it be done?

Comment: I'm not sure you can, I believe the icons attached to a file are taken care of by the operating system.

Comment: It looks like there might be some useful information here: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/jdic_assoc/

Answer (score 1):

Executables (.exe files on Windows) are the only files I know of which have individually "customizable" icons. All other files are given the same icon according to their file extension. For example, html files may have the Internet Explorer or Mozilla Firefox logo depending on the application that opens them by default. pdf files usually have the Adobe logo. As 'ulmangt' indicated, you can specify your own icons for files with specific file extensions by configuring the program used to open them by default. Good luck!